# Multiple behavior spaces

Tags: netlogo

I have a simulation with no global values. Instead the two things that are changed between experiments are the breeds being used, and the number of ticks in the setup (how many turns before the behavior space starts recording results)

Currently I'm duplicating each behaviour space and making the minor changes, is there a better way to do this so that I can program all the behavior spaces runs at once?

Comment: In general, it would help a lot if you posted some code for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'll do that. The only reason I haven't so far is that the simulation I'm using has been split into over a dozen files.

Comment: I understand. But if all those files are variations on a same model with only minor differences, I strongly urge you to merge them, whether it's by applying the technique I suggested below or some other method... ! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways to do this, but since you don't give us a lot of information about what you're trying to do, I'm going to propose something very general. You should be able to adapt it to your needs.

Here is a simplistic model with two breeds (`alphas` and `betas`):

```
breed [ alphas alpha ]
breed [ betas beta ]

globals [
  experiment-id ; this could be a chooser in your interface
  breed-to-use
  num-steps-after-setup
]

to setup
  clear-all
  ifelse experiment-id = 0 [
    set breed-to-use alphas
    set num-steps-after-setup 25
  ] [
    set breed-to-use betas
    set num-steps-after-setup 50
  ]
  create-turtles 10 [
    set breed breed-to-use
  ]
  reset-ticks
  repeat num-steps-after-setup [ some-step-procedure-that-does-not-tick ]
end
```

You can make `experiment-id` vary in your BehaviorSpace experiment definition:

```
["experiment-id" 0 1]
```

The `ifelse experiment-id = 0` statement in `setup` takes care of setting the other parameters according to which experiment you're running.

---

By the way, having a procedure run at the end of `setup` to delay the recording of steps by BehaviorSpace is probably not a good idea, but it's hard to suggest an alternative without knowing why you want to do that.

Comment: I don't know why Alter wants the delay, but I run models in which I don't care what happens for the first 5000 ticks or so--what's interesting is what happens after the initial noisy behavior has settled into relatively stable states.  As it happens, it's more useful for me to record the data myself, rather than lettering BehaviorSpace do it, so I can ignore what I want.  Another option is to let B.S. collect the data, but then delete it from the csv files later.

Comment: I'm looking into network evolution, so I'd like to see how certain breeds perform depending on the network age. I'm finding BehaviorSpace for running multiple simulations and aggregating the results