# Run Multiple Experiments in BehaviorSpace

Tags: netlogo

I have created several separate experiments in BehaviorSpace and would like to run all the experiments in one execution. I read a potential solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401826/multiple-behavior-spaces) that makes use of an `experiment-number` global variable to set variables according to a parameter set, and then use BehaviorSpace to run each "experiment-number". However, this method would require me to set over 100 individual experiments. Instead, I would like just a few experiments, but each experiment varies parameter values. I would like to somehow perform all experiments automatically in one execution instead of picking each experiment separately from the BehaviorSpace GUI. Does anybody have suggestions on how multiple experiments can be ran automatically? I have read the documentation for headless mode, but it seems this still only offers a method to run a single experiment from the command line. I would ideally accomplish this in headless mode, and be able to put results of each experiment in different files. Your ideas are much appreciated.

```
java -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp NetLogo.jar \
  org.nlogo.headless.Main \
  --model MYMODEL.nlogo \
  --experiment experiment1 \
  --experiment experiment2 \
  --experiment experiment3 \
  --experiment experiment4 \
  --experiment experiment5 \
  --table -
```

Comment: how many BehaviorSpace experiments do you have? Note that I am asking how many names appear in the list when you open the dialogue box, not how many simulations are run within each experiment.

Comment: @JenB I currently have 5 separate experiments. I could condense this down to three or four easily, but no less than three because this would lead to very many parameter sets that I am not interested in.

Comment: I just saw the idea of queuing BehaviorSpace experiments was brought up here: (https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/576) , but perhaps a solution has been found since this was posted.

Comment: So please explain why you don't want to just create a batch file with five lines, each of which runs one experiment?

Comment: After a quick read of batch files, I believe this is what I'm trying to do. Perhaps my task is very novice. I haven't worked with headless mode yet. From your previous comment, and the documentation on headless mode, it sounds like I should try something like:                                                  java -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp NetLogo.jar \
  org.nlogo.headless.Main \
  --model MYMODEL.nlogo \
  --experiment experiment1 \
  --experiment experiment2 \
  --experiment experiment3 \
  --experiment experiment4 \
  --experiment experiment5 \
  --table -

Comment: I have added the command line codes in the original question so that can be more easily read. I will give this a try. Thank you.